# Glitch with bootstrap submenu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I use bootstrap 3, [bootstrap table](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table) and [bootstrap submenu](https://vsn4ik.github.io/bootstrap-submenu/)

I have a bootstrap table. On top of it, i have a button with a submenu.
In the button, i have some glitch.

Strangely, mouse over work only for Annuler, Payer, Comptant and Rembourser.
Also a line start under Payer.

Tried to debug it, but found a solution.

[image]

I have an example here
https://jsfiddle.net/y0pqux38/

```
<div id="toolbar" class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Actions</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-submenu="" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        <li><a id="cancelPaymentAction" tabindex="0">Annuler</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a tabindex="0">Payer</a></li>
        <li class="pull-right"><a data-payment-mode="CASH" tabindex="0">Comptant</a></li>
        <li class="pull-right"><a data-payment-mode="DEBIT" tabindex="0">Débit</a></li>
        <li id="creditCardPaymentAction" class="pull-right"><a data-payment-mode="CREDITCARD" tabindex="0">Carte de crédit</a></li>
        <li class="pull-right"><a data-payment-mode="GIFTCARD" tabindex="0">Carte cadeaux</a></li>
        <li class="pull-right"><a data-payment-mode="CHECK" tabindex="0">Chèque</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li id="refundPaymentAction"><a tabindex="0">Rembourser</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glitch in bootstrap Submenu happens because of `pull-right`. Just remove that from all submenu `li`then everything works fine.

In case you want to submenu li items to be `right aligned`  use `text-right` class in place of `pull-right`

Check Demo [**HERE**](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/MbQZbg?editors=1010)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 centered">
      <div id="toolbar" class="btn-group pull-right">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Actions</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-submenu="" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <li><a id="cancelPaymentAction" tabindex="0">Annuler</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a tabindex="0">Payer</a></li>
          <li><a data-payment-mode="CASH" tabindex="0">Comptant</a></li>
          <li><a data-payment-mode="DEBIT" tabindex="0">Débit</a></li>
          <li id="creditCardPaymentAction"><a data-payment-mode="CREDITCARD" tabindex="0">Carte de crédit</a></li>
          <li><a data-payment-mode="GIFTCARD" tabindex="0">Carte cadeaux</a></li>
          <li><a data-payment-mode="CHECK" tabindex="0">Chèque</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li id="refundPaymentAction"><a tabindex="0">Rembourser</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```